# Unix sub path creation and copy files

Tags: unix

There is file A.lst

```
 A.lst  
 b/pro/c/ab.par  
 b/pro/tam.par  
 b/pro/cc/lam.par
```

We need to create missing folders like mentioned below in the following way and also add _bkp
to the file name and then copy the files to location, as you can see  folder folders c and cc are created  and files are also copied.

Output

```
 b/pro/backpro/c/ab_bap.par 
 b/pro/backpro/tam_bkp.par      
 b/pro/backpro/cc/lam_bkp.par
```

How can this be achieved using for loop.
**** Tried below****.

```
#!/bin/bash  

# Define the source directory. 
source_dir="b/pro"

# Define the destination directory
destination_dir="b/pro/backpro"   

# Loop through each file in 
A.lst  #
 while IFS= read -r file; do  
****Extract the filename without                 extension****  
filename=$(basename "$file" | sed             's/\.par$//')  

# Append "_bkp.par" to the          filename  #. 
new_filename="${filename}_bkp.par"

# Construct the source and     destination paths
source_path="$source_dir/$file"
destination_path="$destination_dir/$new_filename"  

# Create the destination 
directory if it doesn't exist  
mkdir -p "$(dirname        "$destination_path")"
**Copy the file to the  
destination with the new        filename**  
cp "$source_path"      "$destination_path"  
echo "Copied $source_path to         $destination_path"    
done
```

Comment: I have made minor mods to your text in hopes of making your question understandable, but I don't think it is my responsibilty to fix the actual code. (Leaving `***` chars without a preceding `#` char will certainly cause trouble.). Fix anything flagged when you copy/paste yourr code into https://shellcheck.net and if that doesn't solve your problem, Indent your code properly and include a note like "shellcheck verified". In the future use the `{}` tool from the **Edit** menu to format mouse-slected text as `code/data/output/exactTextOfErrMsgs`. . (Good screen name!) Good luck.